# Java TimeZoneUpdater crashes with java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, timezone

I tried running this on several machines but always get an error.
I downloaded the tzupdater tool from the official Oracle page.

I run this:

```
sudo java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -f -l
```

And get this:

```
Using http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tzdata-latest.tar.gz as source for tzdata bundle.
java.home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.7.0_80
tzupdater version 2.1.1-b01
JRE tzdata version: tzdata2017c
Downloaded file to /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/tz.tmp/tzdata.tar.gz
java.io.EOFException
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TzRuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:264)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:254)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:163)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:78)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.ExternalModule.extractFiles(ExternalModule.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.run(TimezoneUpdater.java:209)
    at com.sun.tools.tzupdater.TimezoneUpdater.main(TimezoneUpdater.java:643)
```

May I note that this happens also when the machine doesn't have the latest tzdata version (and actual upgrade is needed).

Please help!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the compression of the file that the tool downloads. Like one would expect if it doesn’t get the whole file, for instance. The output mentions the local file name, so unless the tool deletes it again (as it should), you may want to test if you can uncompress it by hand or you get a similar error.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I already tried this. Unfortunately, the tool deletes the file. When I download the file manually it gets extracted correctly. So I wonder maybe this is a connection problem (the tool might not be able to fetch the file properly from the web).

Comment: And you get this message every time you try? With exactly the same stacktrace on different machines??

Comment: Yep, exactly the same stack trace :-/

Comment: I get a stacktrace much like yours. Methods are the same. Not all of the line numbers, this may come from a slightly different version of the JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the default "latest" jar (which is fetched automatically by the tool) is problematic.
Running the command with a specific tzdata2017c.tar.gz directly works totally fine.

```
sudo java -jar tzupdater.jar -v -f -l https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2017c.tar.gz
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug that Oracle should like to hear about. I’m not sure how to go about reporting it, though, so don’t feel (too) obliged. :-)

Comment: :-) Thanks, mate!